# TakeWhile() with conditions in multiple lines

Tags: c#, parsing

I have a text file with a few thousand lines of texts. A Readlines() function reads each line of the file and yield return the lines.

I need to skip the lines until a condition is met, so it's pretty easy like this:

```
var lines = ReadLines().SkipWhile(x => !x.Text.Contains("ABC Header"))
```

The problem I am trying to solve is there is another condition -- once I find the line with "ABC Header", the following line must contain "XYZ Detail". Basically, the file contains multiple lines that have the text "ABC Header" in it, but not all of these lines are followed by "XYZ Detail". I only need those where both of these lines are present together.

How do I do this? I tried to add .Where after the SkipWhile, but that doesn't guarantee the "XYZ Detail" line is immediately following the "ABC Header" line. Thanks!

Comment: _"I only need those where both of these lines are present together."_ - And your result shall contain both of them?

Comment: I actually really think you would come to a solution faster if you ditched LINQ. Try with a good old while loop?

Comment: Fildor, yes, the results needs to contain both lines. Unfortunately, I can't change how the ReadLines() are written, it's in another base class that I have no control of.

Comment: _"I can't change how the ReadLines()"_ - I don't think you'd have to?

Comment: I did use while loop originally like this var lines = ReadLines();

                for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count(); i++) ... however, for some reason, I end up in a loop that never ends -- it keeps calling the same Readlines() over and over again.

Comment: Can you post the signature of Readlines()? I am setting up a test project at this moment.

Comment: var lines = ReadLInes(); and then a for loop.

Comment: using (var reader = new LineReader(File.OpenRead(Loader.FilePath)))
                foreach (var line in reader.ReadLines())
                {
                    yield return line;
                }

        public IEnumerable<Line> ReadLines()
        {
            var i = 0;
            string text;
            while ((text = _reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(i);
                yield return new Line(++i, text);
            }
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
using Experiment72045808;

string? candidate = null;
List<(string, string)> results = new();
foreach (var entry in FileReader.ReadLines())
{
    if (entry is null) continue;
    if (candidate is null)
    {
        if (entry.Contains("ABC Header"))
        {
            candidate = entry;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // This will handle two adjacend ABC Header - Lines.
        if (entry.Contains("ABC Header"))
        {
            candidate = entry;
            continue;
        }
        
        // Add to result set and reset.
        if (entry.Contains("XYZ Detail"))
        {
            results.Add((candidate, entry));
            candidate = null;
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Found results:");
foreach (var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{result.Item1} / {result.Item2}");
}
```

resulted in output:

```
Found results:
ABC Header 2 / XYZ Detail 2
ABC Header 3 / XYZ Detail 3
```

For input File

```
Line 1
Line 2
ABC Header 1
Line 4
Line 5
ABC Header 2
XYZ Detail 2
Line 6
Line7
ABC Header 3
XYZ Detail 3
Line 8
Line 9
```

`FileReader.ReadResults()` in my test is implemented nearly identical to yours.

Comment: Instead of your foreach (var entry in FileReader.ReadLines()), I used for(int i = 0; i <= lines.Count(); i++), do you think the Count() method could be problematic for the yield return ReadLines()?

Comment: I do think so. `foreach` will be lowered to using the Iterator. A plain old for disrupts the whole thing. See also: [yield (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield)

Comment: You are right fildor! The Count() method messed it up, just use regular foreach() loop does the job, you da man!